# "Steamroller" to describe a person as very determined

Tags: meaning, nouns, metaphors

Can "steamroller" be used to describe a person like in the following sentence?

> He is like a steamroller; nothing will stop him from getting work done.

Or are there any other meanings to the word I don't know of? (English is not my mother tongue.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Like a steamroller" is acceptable usage for describing a person.  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/steamroller) (Collins) cites one meaning of steamroller as "an overpowering force or a person with such force that overcomes all opposition."  The New York Times has many examples where people are described as such.  [Here's one](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/12/18/sports/hockey-rangers-have-shaky-start-but-a-strong-finish.html): "the 6-foot-6, 245-pound Worrell, who played like a steamroller last night."  [Another](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/02/01/arts/donahue-vs-winfrey-a-clash-of-talk-titans.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm): "Oprah came on like a steamroller but he is not showing any attrition." [Sylvia Plath](http://books.google.com/books?id=UJ628vQBsYAC&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=%22like%20a%20steamroller%22%20literature&source=bl&ots=Tm7f401L7F&sig=y6WHpFgrUt7UTheJvxoPouWKNIE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PVG9T-zxHoKg6QGkw5ymAg&ved=0CJ4CEOgBMAU4Mg#v=onepage&q=%22like%20a%20steamroller%22%20literature&f=false) wrote "I need a strong mate: I do not want to crush and subdue him like a steamroller."

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the best choice "steamroll" as a verb generally means to push through some process/solution crushing all opposition

"Prime Minister Harper intends to steamroller his elimination of...."

"Tories: we'll use ancient laws to steamroller through welfare cuts"

Comment: can you suggest a better word?

Comment: Unstoppable, tenacious

Comment: "He works like a Trojan," perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I'd avoid that one in the U.S.  Yes, it's a [perfectly valid idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+like+a+trojan), but not heard often here. Plus, _Trojan_ is a leading brand of condoms here, and that's what a lot of people think of when they hear the word.

Comment: I would drop the _-er_ in your examples. At least that's the way I usually hear it used.

Comment: Those are direct quotes from the newspapers

Comment: "He's like a dog with a bone."

Comment: @J.R. I suppose it depends what he is working at, really. It could prove an interesting idiom.....

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I never really understood that. The Trojans were the ones being besieged. Other than a certain gullibility when it came to large animal sculpture - all they had to do was lay back and watch the Greeks throwing themselves against the walls?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree with mgb, "working like a Trojan" could be taken as "works and works but at the end is defeated by a smarter oppponent" lol