# Synonyms for the phrase "stop at nothing"

Tags: synonyms, catch-phrases

I am writing a report about someone and would like to convey the sense that he was desperate for success and overly ambitious. I've used phrases like "stop at nothing" to capture the ambition and the willingness to do set aside morals and/or break the law. I would like to use different expressions as I think "stop at nothing" is a bit cliche.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want a *different* cliche to use instead of this one?

Comment: @Robusto yes people do that sometimes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few questions on this site with helpful terms including this one: ["Steamroller" to describe a person as very determined](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68654/steamroller-to-describe-a-person-as-very-determined)

***"Unstoppable"*** is very straightforward

***"Relentless"*** is good too as is the related ***"unrelenting"***

> Definition of "relentless" from the Merriam-Webster online dictionary: showing or promising no abatement of severity, intensity, strength, or pace : unrelenting

**EDIT**

Since the OP refined the definition in the comment, below, I think ***"driven"***, ***"irrepressible"*** and ***"ruthless"*** work very well also.

Comment: steamroller doesn't work for me, I'm describing someone engaged in acts of subterfuge and willing to backstab. He is a small screw in a large organization if you will, definitely not a dominant steamroller.

Answer (score -1):

intractable, maybe, although it means more unmanageable.

Comment: It's an excellent term, but [intractable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intractable) has a different meaning to the one asked for.

Answer (score -2):

By any means necessary..... Pull out all the stops.....ferocious at any cost.... Cut throat assassin

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. Try to focus on one or two options giving definitions and examples. On this site more thorough answers are encouraged.