# To forcefully do something you're not supposed to do

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What's the correct verb to say **to forcefully do something you are not supposed to do** or **to attempt acts in the attitude of 'just go for it'**? Here, "forcefully" does not necessarily mean physical force. E.g.

- You push a pin into a plug, the plug does not fit, so **you ____** and push it harder than you should, possibly deforming the pin in the process
- There is a traffic jam ahead. **You ____** and switch to a different lane to continue the journey. There is enough space, but the markings on the road say you cannot switch lanes there.
- Someone asks you to perform a difficult piece at a concert. You promise to perform despite being well aware that the piece is beyond your ability and **you're ____-ing**, hoping that perhaps you have practiced hard enough and the audience will not notice.

The important elements in those examples are:

1. You are well aware that the act is **against the odds**
2. You are well aware you are **not supposed** to act like that (i.e. an alternative solution with a lower risk exists, but it's likely more complicated and you're lazy)

Note that the outcome of the attempt is uncertain. Sometimes you succeed, sometimes you fail.

For those who know Cantonese, it's "格硬黎".

---

Thanks everyone for their suggestions. Unfortunately I cannot give credit to multiple answers, but many of them are good:

- *force*
- *brute-force*
- *put a square peg into a round hole*
- *just fake it*
- *brash*

*Improvise* doesn't really fit - the action may be well planned but still against the odds.

Comment: Single-word-request? Phrase? Idiom or formal?

Comment: It's informal usage. Preferably single-word, but a short phrase which accurately expresses the idea would do a well.

Comment: From your examples ... that's a lot to ask of a SWR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

*To act in a **devil-may-care** manner.*

a very casual attitude; a worry free or carefree attitude

*To act in a **like a bull in a china shop***

> [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA181&dq=%22bull%20in%20a%20china%20shop%22%20idiom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=peIUVazHOsmKsQSh64C4Dw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22bull%20in%20a%20china%20shop%22%20idiom&f=false)  - Page 181 2008 -
>   **like a bull in a china shop** If someone is like a bull in a china shop, they are very careless in the way that they move or behave

More:

**go for broke**

**letting it fly**

**reckless**

**taking a chance**

**try to crash through the soup**

**shoot the works**

**hazard all**

**plunge**

**take a flier**

(both of finance) **speculate**, **sell short**

**go out on a limb**

**play fast and loose**

**stick one's neck out**

**take a shot (or stab) in the dark**

**tempt fate (or fortune)**

**trust to chance**

Comment: Nice list of idioms. You mean that they are all interchangeable ?  Do they all fit OP request? Or are there expressions in the list which may better express the concept OP wants to convey?

Answer (score 4):

"You cannot **just do whatever you want**. You must obey the rules".

or,

"You cannot **just throw caution to the wind**.

or,

"We couldn't find any player for the concert, so he just **improvised**.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're talking about *brute force*.  A **steamroller** might convey the appropriate imagery.

> [He is like a steamroller; nothing will stop him from getting work done.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68654/steamroller-to-describe-a-person-as-very-determined)

Someone who acts carelessly this way may do so with **reckless abandon**.

Comment: +1 *The Steelers have played sloppily in the last three weeks, and they are not the team that steamrolled through the regular season in '04.* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steamroll -- Substantiate the suggestion to make it a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the verb *force* enough?

> - You **forced** a pin into the plug and deformed it in the process
> - There is a traffic jam ahead. You **forced your way** to a different lane to continue the journey. There is enough space, but the
>     markings on the road say you cannot switch lanes there.
> - Someone asks you to perform a difficult piece at a concert. You **forced yourself** to perform despite being well aware that the piece is beyond your ability, hoping that perhaps you have practiced hard
>     enough and the audience will not observe this
> - You cannot **force it**. You must obey the rules.
> - We couldn't find any player for the concert, so he just **forced himself to do it**.

Comment: **force** is good, however it does not convey the idea that there is another solution which you're *supposed* to follow

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you mean to "buck the system" in one word might be to "defy" as in against the odds she defied the norm ...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot:

- *fit a round peg in a square hole*.
- *ride the shoulder*.
- *just fake it*.

---

> You cannot [flippantly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flippant) *yield yourself to your own devices*. You must obey the rules.

- So he just **winged it**.

---

I believe this is the attitude you're looking for:

With all these edits I'm just going to have to throw in the towel and say ***fuck it***, just use/do whatever you ***fucking*** want. -I hope that didn't *rub you the wrong way*. I'm not trying to *go against the grain* here.

Comment: I think we all know what to call the second example ;)

Comment: Creative problem-solving? Anarchy? Wha?

Comment: @LittleEva See, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites). 
GEOCHET's answer was much funnier before they changed their bio.

Comment: Yeah, the whole thread was amusing

Comment: Oops! I hadn't seen your "**wing it**" suggestion, you should probably place it in bold.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It was a late add from me and the OP. Your *improvise* is excellent.

Comment: I like *fit a round peg in a square hole*. It quite accurately conveys the spirit of it.

Answer (score 2):

Since answers are spreading into other parts of speech, I would use **[brash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brash?s=t)** or **brashly** to refer to the action or the way it was performed.

Here are a few definitions of the word, which all suggest an aggressive, somewhat reckless spirit.

> Brash (adj.)
>
> 1. impertinent; impudent; tactless: "a brash young man".
> 2. hasty; rash; impetuous.
> 3. energetic or highly spirited, especially in an irreverent way; zesty: "a brash new musical".

To use a couple of your examples:

- There is a traffic jam ahead so you *brashly* switch lanes, crossing double yellow lines, to continue the journey.
- You are well aware that the piece is beyond your ability and you're *brashly* hoping that perhaps you have practiced hard enough and the audience will not observe this.

Answer (score 0):

Crossing an unbroken (continuous/solid) white line in order to avoid a traffic jam is illegal, so *you're breaking the law*.

> By switching to a different lane, I was *technically*  breaking the law.

Admittedly the phrase *break the law* sounds too close to being a ‘criminal’ act, so a motorist might say

> I had to **bend the rules** and change lane.

[**bend the rules**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bend-the-rules): (informal) to ignore rules or change them to suit one's own convenience

Answer (score -1):

> To wing it.

Especially for your last example (the concert).

> Are you ready for the concert tonight? Nah, I'm just going to wing it.

I would use it for the second and third examples, but not the first. They describe different base scenarios to me. For the first example, I would probably say:

> (You can't) force it.